# mock тестирование

Tags: java, junit

- *jmock 2.6.0* (Java 6) это последняя библиотека которую я нашел на их офф.сайте.
  Я использую Java 8, поэтому у меня практически весь jmock 2.6.0 deprecated.
- *mockito* скачал, но Eclipse не видит эту библиотеку, хотя она добавлена как положено. если точнее то пакеты других библиотек подсвечивают коричневым цветом, а этой серым. Maven пока не знаю.

Подскажите чем лучше создавать mock обьект?

Comment: Лично я предпочитаю эту либу использовать: http://mockito.org/ а вообще вы задали вопрос-опросник, что не гуд.

Comment: @Vartlok я скачал оттуда библиотеку, но при установлении она некорректно отображается, может такое быть из-за того что я не использую мавен?

Comment: Вы её использовать пробовали?

Comment: @Vartlok пробовал конечно, не видит ее еклипс

Comment: Я попробовал добавить эту либу как Reference Library и у меня всё работает. Видимо, вы как-то не так добавляете.

Comment: @Vartlok `Build Path - Add to  Build Path` так добавил в проект данную библиотеку. "пакеты других библиотек подсвечивают коричневым цветом, а этой серым"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31797/discussion-between-makson-and-vartlok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я предпочитаю [mockito](http://mockito.org/).

Скачивать надо файл mockito-all-1.10.19.jar. Все остальные файл вспомогательные, с исходными кодами и документацией.

Есть еще [easymock](http://easymock.org/)

Сравнение между собой можно посмотреть [тут](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock).